# How to return a dataframe for different values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 522x329 with sites for columns showing the sum of observed species at that site for that particular week in each year.

I want to return a dataframe for each site that responds to each week within the year with 0 values and the same for those with values > 1.

For example, here is a reproducible code + glimpse of the dataset:

```
structure(list(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), 
    week = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `IP20 0HR` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `IP20 9LR` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP20 9PJ` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP20 9QE` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP21 4NT` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP21 4NZ` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP21 4PT` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP21 4TR` = c(12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP22 2AP` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP22 2BP` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP22 2DZ` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L), `IP22 2JG` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP22 4BD` = c(9L, 7L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 0L
    ), `IP22 4BE` = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 8L), `IP22 4PH` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP22 4YW` = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L
    ), `IP22 5SB` = c(15L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 17L, 16L), `IP22 5SR` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP22 5SX` = c(0L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 0L, 
    0L), `IP22 5TY` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 1JF` = c(8L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 6L), `IP24 1LB` = c(7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP24 1PN` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 1QR` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 1RA` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP24 1UE` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2AD` = c(14L, 
    8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2JZ` = c(5L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP24 2LD` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2LW` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2PU` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `IP24 2TD` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2TQ` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2YR` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L
    ), `IP24 2YW` = c(10L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 2ZA` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `IP24 3EP` = c(12L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), `IP24 3HG` = c(0L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

 year week IP20 0HR IP20 9LR IP20 9PJ IP20 9QE IP21 4NT IP21 4NZ IP21 4PT IP21 4TR IP22 2AP IP22 2BP IP22 2DZ IP22 2JG
1 2010    1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       12        0        0        0        0
2 2011    1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
3 2012    1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
4 2013    1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
5 2014    1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
6 2015    1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        9        0
  IP22 4BD IP22 4BE IP22 4PH IP22 4YW IP22 5SB IP22 5SR IP22 5SX IP22 5TY IP24 1JF IP24 1LB IP24 1PN IP24 1QR IP24 1RA IP24 1UE
1        9        7        0        6       15        0        0        0        8        7        0        0        0        0
2        7        8        0        5       25        0        9        0        4        0        0        0        0        0
3        0        9        0        7       25        0        9        0        2        0        0        0        0        0
4        7        7        0        5       22        0       12        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
5        3        8        0        3       17        0        0        0        6        0        0        0        0        0
6        0        8        0        7       16        0        0        0        6        0        0        0        0        0
  IP24 2AD IP24 2JZ IP24 2LD IP24 2LW IP24 2PU IP24 2TD IP24 2TQ IP24 2YR IP24 2YW IP24 2ZA IP24 3EP IP24 3HG
1       14        5        0        0        0        0        0        0       10        0       12        0
2        8        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       11        0       14       10
3        2        5        0        0        0        0        0        0       11        0        0        8
4        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        7
5        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        4
6        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       10        0        0        0        9
```

I want an output showing something like:

```
df1
year  week  IP20 0HR   IP20 9LR   IP20 9PJ    ...
2010   33     3           2           1       ...
2011   2      1           7           1       ...
2012   3      2           3           1       ...
2013   4      2           1           2       ...
 .
 .
2019   1      1           1           1       ...

&

df2
year  week   IP20 0HR   IP20 9LR   IP20 9PJ    ...
2010   1       0           0          0        ...
2010   5       0           0          0        ...
2011   11      0           0          0        ...
 .
 .
 .
2019   3       0            0          0        ...
```

I have tried:

```
pat <- data.frame(method_three[, 3:379] == 0)
```

which only returns true or false values, not like above, and I want all the values not 0 not in the dataframe, and those greater than 0 in a separate dataframe.

EXTRA:
Then separetly embed the columns into a list so I could call each column individually to print out their values

Comment: DO you want the output only for `IP20 0HR`

Comment: I wish for the output to be of all columns. I only used `IP20 0HR` as an example output as it was easier to print and show.

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the input example.  THe expected showed seems to be for a different dataset

Comment: I do not think this is necessary. The output will be with all the sites as columns. However, I can edit and add a few more sites for clarification. EDIT: Good eye, I noticed how you might have been confused. I corrected it now I believe.

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(year, week) %>% summarise(across(everything(),  ~ sum(. > 0)))` and `df1 %>% group_by(year, week) %>% summarise(across(everything(),  ~ sum(. == 0)))`

Comment: IN the example, there is only a single week 1, so, I assume it needs to be grouped by 'year', 'week'

Comment: I think I see what you did, when the values are `== 0` it returns a `1` and a `0` otherwise, same for the previous code. Is there a way to extract only those with values `1` in the second code and place that into a dataframe, and those values `> 0` from code 1 and put that into a separate dataframe. Or would this not work because some columns may have differrent lengths so there must be something to fill in the missing values to make up these lengths?

Comment: When you extract for each column, the length would be different based on whether the element is greater than 0 or not.  Not sure how you wanted it.  If it is a small example and expected output, it would be easier to crosscheck